# Пересечение времени SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, streaming

Имеется таблица с 3-мя столбцами id, start(timestamp with time zone), duration(interval). В этой таблице обозначены начало и продолжительность запланированных онлайн уроков. Проблема в том, что сервер не способен поддерживать более трех конференций одновременно. Нужен запрос, что бы определить какие трансляции или в какое время пересекаются, что бы заранее это отлавливать и переносить запланированные занятия. Например, при наличии трансляций в

1. 15:00 на 45 минут
2. 15:00 на 1 час
3. 15:15 на 1 час 15 минут
4. 15:30 на 45 минут

видим пересечение, которое не "вытянет" наш сервер, запрос должен найти это, и выдать, например, "косячный" интервал или id этих уроков.
Реально ли это решить в SQL (postgres), или придется через Python?

```
create table lessons 
(id bigserial not null constraint str_pkey primary key, duration interval, sch_at timestamp with time zone)
insert into lessons
 (id, sch_at, duration) values 
(1234, '2020-09-19 15:30:00.000000', '0 years 0 mons 0 days 1 hours 15 mins 0.00 secs'), 
(1235, '2020-09-19 15:45:00.000000', '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 45 mins 0.00 secs');
```

Спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да запросто. Конвертируешь расписание в пару начало-конец. Потом начала пишешь с весом 1, концы -1. И считаешь сумму с накоплением на каждый кол времени. 4 или больше - криминал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схематично:

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT time tt, time+duration td FROM table ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT tt, 1 w FROM cte1 UNION ALL SELECT td, -1 FROM cte1 )
SELECT DISTINCT tt, SUM(w) OVER (ORDER BY tt) ww FROM cte2;
```

Первая же четвёрка или более в ww - это точка перегрузки сервера.

Comment: Привет! Спасибо большое за ответ! Если я все верно понял, мне стоит изменить time, duration и table на мои названия. В таком случае получаю что-то вообще непонятное со значениями ww от 1 до примерно 650. Возможно вопрос глупый, я пока в оконных не силен)

Comment: Create не могу предоставить, увы
Все три столбца всегда валидны с типами данных, которые я указал
Иногда бывает что start = null, но я могу это отсечь через where
Давайте предположим, что таблица неизменна и расписана на месяц вперед
Скрин добавил в вопрос

Comment: Ни в коем случае) Просто если у вас есть время, возможность и желание подсказать, то будет круто) Create мне не жалко, у меня просто его нет

Comment: Добавил create и insert в вопрос

Comment: @Michael Вот Вы пишете: "сервер не способен поддерживать более трех конференций одновременно". ТРЁХ. Теперь  - вы даёте пример данных. В котором ДВЕ записи. Не надо быть академиком, чтобы и без всякого запроса сказать - сервер справится.

Comment: Я отправил пример, строчек (записей) более тысячи, они все аналогичные. Почти каждый день бывают пересечения, по 15 уроков в день